# Facebook login uses same account every time users login

Tags: android, facebook

I use Facebook SDK to let users sign in to the android app via Facebook account. When the user taps the Facebook login button for the first time, it produces a dialog to choose the account. Again, when the user logs out and decides to login with different Facebook account, it doesn't prompt to choose the account, it logs in the account the user had chose the previous time

Comment: logout from the facebook sdk, when you successfully get the info from the faecebook

Comment: A user is only allowed to have one account. So there should be no case where the user needs to login with a different account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to logout from Facebook.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
```

Answer (score 1):

wherever you used login code put 
`LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()` before login 
By this when you trying to login then it will logout previous account and login for new account.

Comment: try this 
 if (LoginManager.getInstance() != null) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }

Answer (score 1):

For logout use this

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
```

when you login , there should not be any active token instance. so in your case before login code , just do logout.